# Typescript interface + constants vs class for defining enum-like object

Tags: javascript, typescript, aws-cdk

I am new to typescript, and I am trying to define an enum-like class with some additional attributes. I have seen there are two different approaches of doing this:

1. Using a class, similar to what I would do in Java:

```
export class AwsRegion {
 
     public static US_EAST_1 = new AwsRegion('us-east-1');
     public static EU_WEST_1 = new AwsRegion('eu-west-1');
     public static US_WEST_2 = new AwsRegion('us-west-2');
 
     private name: string;
 
     constructor(name: string) {
         this.name = name;
     }
 
     public getName(): string {
         return this.name;
     }
 }
```

2. Using interface + typescript constants:

```
 export interface AwsRegion {
     readonly name: string;
 }

export const US_EAST_1: AwsRegion = { name: 'us-east-1' };
export const EU_WEST_1: AwsRegion = { name: 'eu-west-1' };
export const US_WEST_2: AwsRegion = { name: 'us-west-2' };
```

Is there any advantage to any of the two, or one that is more idiomatic in typescript than the other?

Thanks,

Comment: FYI the CDK is available in Java

Comment: TypeScript has enums. You could create a class that takes a variant of the enum as a parameter. What's your use case / what do you want the API to look like?
The code you currently have looks pretty good actually. Depending on how you need this to run and which variants you actually need, it might be smarter to only initialize the class instances or objects when you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript supports lots of programming styles. To get a feel for the idioms that the AWS team chose for CDK, check out [CDK github source](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk). The [lambda package](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-lambda/lib) source is a good place to start.

The CDK often uses static factory methods for configuration:

```js
export class Runtime {
  // ...
  public static readonly NODEJS_14_X = new Runtime('nodejs14.x', RuntimeFamily.NODEJS, { supportsInlineCode: true });
  public static readonly PYTHON_2_7 = new Runtime('python2.7', RuntimeFamily.PYTHON, { supportsInlineCode: true });
```

Regarding your examples, note that as written, both approaches allow callers to create invalid configuration objects. Typescript will accept `mars` as a region without complaint:

```js
// class
const mars: AwsRegion = new AwsRegion('mars');

// plain old object
const MARS_REGION: AwsRegion = { name: 'mars' };
```

You can fix this. For the class approach: make the constructor private.

```js
private constructor(name: string) {} 

// TS Error: Constructor of class 'AwsRegion' is private and only accessible within the class declaration
const mars: AwsRegion = new AwsRegion("mars")
```

For the POJO version, narrow the valid regions in the interface

```js
interface AwsRegion {
  readonly name: 'us-east-1' | 'eu-west-1' | 'us-west-2';
}

// TS Error:  Type '"mars"' is not assignable to type '"us-east-1" | "eu-west-1" | "us-west-2"'
const MARS_REGION: AwsRegion = { name: 'mars' };
```

Here is the TS Playground [live code version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/BTCUF4D4AIG8Ch7WgYwDYEMDOXoEEB3LAJQFMBzASwHsA7OJaR5ZABwFcAjNSlaLAC4YBvaAFUAygH0AongkAVKQEZo4aLVIF8RMlTrAA5OywBaUtgGnlh0AG5mLDt1GDhomWKkB1GYpVqGlo6JBQ0tEak7KYEpILWtg4sTlw8fG4ifJI+fkoATIGa2oSh+hHGZrHxeYmMjmwATpQAbsKkGhgAtqQAXPwCTbTkSUzJjS1tqHSCDewoAtQNwLRdvf2D5KAMY2MCABaUWAB0K92FqyPJAL51O85p0OSkAgByq2B9M5RD2zssDc92A16PtDicLvVoDdkDdGChpgJoBZBIESnpwkdPDl-Mojk9Xu9QIhkPDaCjOhgGrh1EUQuiDAAiClUhlEuHTahoUhHNDUcjAZm4b5uWgoUjUABmdLCdDZiAEAE9WO0AGoYHgAE3pZMCFXMlgS0AAPtBDFEYnErDZjaaTBbqoZEIxvgJSA0JRgxdKygUEDsARgNXQ0AqOt0+nrkVbDDazdEqtHY3aE6YaiNYSSEeJpHIcX00TLaAV1LAw2tIwbrVcRqSUVjfHnveFi3AyxHzSmqzWs9kG-l87pCy3S6dy8nLamY9XiVMyYjBdqB6Vm4ER6sI4LDNDRtAXW6PV6C2UAMJ0CWUci-ZKjz4Db7DSGHPBoXmxDV9TjUTkWWh2Hewq5QDAeAgA) of these examples.